# Loop through a function which groups by column variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with columns in the form Bal, Q, W, E, R, T, Y. 
I have written a function which allows me to summarise based on the column of my choice.

```
BandFunction <- function(x, y){ y <- enquo(y)
    return(x %>%
    group_by(!!y) %>% 
    summarise(Vol=n(),
              Bal = sum(Bal)) %>% 
      mutate(
             'Vol %' = Vol/sum(Vol),
             'Bal %' = Bal/sum(Bal)
      )
    )
    }
```

I wish to loop through this function to make multiple data sets. I have tried the following;

```
Cols <- c("Q", "W", "E","R","T","Y")
ListofDFs <- list()
for(i in 1:length(Col)){
        ListofDFs[[i]] <- BandFunction(df, Cols[i])}
    return(ListofDFs)
        }
```

But does not work, as it it will produce `data.frames` with a column title called `Cols[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you solve this

I changed your function with `{{ y }}` (Doesn't really matter, works with `enquo(y)` as well).

```
BandFunction <- function(x, y){ 
return(x %>%
         group_by({{y}}) %>% 
         summarise(Vol=n(),
                   Bal = sum(mpg)) %>% 
         mutate(
           'Vol %' = Vol/sum(Vol),
           'Bal %' = Bal/sum(Bal)
         )
)
}
```

Create a list of variables you care about (In your case this is the `QWERTY` vector)

```
my_vars <- names(mtcars)[2:3]

## check my_vars %>% syms()

my_vars %>%
# The syms command is key to generate a list of columns to loop over
  syms() %>%
# now call and don't forget to use !!var
# otherwise you are asking for the column `var` to get evaluated
  purrr::map(function(var) BandFunction(mtcars, !!var))
```

Mind that I'm using `mtcars` and `mpg` to get a reproducible example. Change that for your purposes

The result is

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
    cyl   Vol   Bal `Vol %` `Bal %`
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4    11  293.   0.344   0.456
2     6     7  138.   0.219   0.215
3     8    14  211.   0.438   0.329

[[2]]
# A tibble: 27 x 5
    disp   Vol   Bal `Vol %` `Bal %`
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  71.1     1  33.9  0.0312  0.0527
 2  75.7     1  30.4  0.0312  0.0473
 3  78.7     1  32.4  0.0312  0.0504
 4  79       1  27.3  0.0312  0.0425
 5  95.1     1  30.4  0.0312  0.0473
 6 108       1  22.8  0.0312  0.0355
 7 120.      1  21.5  0.0312  0.0334
 8 120.      1  26    0.0312  0.0404
 9 121       1  21.4  0.0312  0.0333
10 141.      1  22.8  0.0312  0.0355
# … with 17 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Function <- function(x, y){ y <- sym(y)
return(x %>%
         group_by(!!y) %>% 
         summarise(Vol=n(),
                   Bal = sum(Bal)) %>% 
         mutate(
           'Vol %' = Vol/sum(Vol),
           'Bal %' = Bal/sum(Bal)
         )
)
}

df<-data.frame(Vol=seq(1,50,1),Bal=seq(1,100,2),Q=sample(LETTERS,50,replace = T),R=sample(letters,50,replace = T))
Cols <- c("Q", "R")
ListofDFs <- list()
for(i in 1:length(Cols)){
  ListofDFs[[i]] <- Function(df, Cols[i])
}
```

There are two typos in the code: in the for loop Col should = Cols and there is a lose curly bracket in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without using NSE is using `group_by_at` which accepts string arguments.

```
Cols <- c("Q", "W", "E","R","T","Y")
library(dplyr)

purrr::map(Cols, ~df %>%
                   group_by_at(.x) %>% 
                   summarise(Vol=n(),
                             Bal = sum(Bal)) %>% 
                   mutate('Vol %' = Vol/sum(Vol),
                          'Bal %' = Bal/sum(Bal)))
```